# Python replacement of switch case into dictionary (for function calls)

Tags: python, dictionary, discord.py, switch-statement

I'm trying to experiment with a replacement for switch/cases in Python that I had found online. It works quite well for most variables but I'm trying to make it such that I can call functions but I'm getting some strange behavior.

This is my python function using discord py:

```
async def reminder(self, ctx, *args): #args is the input from the user
     reminder_operations = {
            'add': await self.reminder_add(ctx),
            'modify': await self.reminder_modify(ctx),
            'delete': await self.reminder_delete(ctx),
            'deleteall': await self.reminder_delete_all(ctx)
        }
     reminder_operations[args[0]] # in this test, args[0] = 'add'
```

In this snippet above, every function in the dictionary is called.

```
reminder_operations = {
            'add': self.reminder_add(ctx),
            'modify': self.reminder_modify(ctx),
            'delete': self.reminder_delete(ctx),
            'deleteall': self.reminder_delete_all(ctx)
        }
        await reminder_operations[args[0]]
```

In this snippet above, it works (only `self.reminder_add()` is called) but pycharm throws a RuntimeWarning:

```
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'reminder_cog.reminder_modify' was never awaited
  ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
D:\Downloads\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py:85: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'reminder_cog.reminder_delete' was never awaited
  ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
D:\Downloads\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py:85: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'reminder_cog.reminder_delete_all' was never awaited
  ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

Should I just ignore these warnings? Is there a better way to go about dictionary switch-cases for functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are **calling** *all* of the functions (without await) when defining the dictionary and storing their return values in the dictionary instead of references to the functions.

```
async def reminder(self, ctx, *args):    
    reminder_operations = {
                    'add': self.reminder_add,
                    'modify': self.reminder_modify,
                    'delete': self.reminder_delete,
                    'deleteall': self.reminder_delete_all
                }
        
    return await reminder_operations[args[0]](ctx)
```

Comment: This does not quite make sense to me for one reason: Each of these functions has a bot message send function and a blank return. Wouldn't this mean, under your explanation, that the bot sends 4 messages under both snippets? Since it would be executing every function but only giving me access to the return value when calling upon the dictionary

Comment: @SergioN. I don't know how these functions are implemented so I'm not sure what messages are or aren't being sent, but if you want to try it out add a print statement at the beginning of each function and you'll see that they're all executed each time you call your reminder function.

Comment: Wow this is fascinating behavior you're completely right, there was some other async interference that I removed to test this and they do all execute. Didn't know I could just join non-string objects with a parentheses to call functions. Is my approach considered poor syntax?

Comment: @SergioN. Fascinating indeed :) This isn't poor syntax per se, however the code you wrote behaves differently from your intention in this particular case. For a different function it might make sense to store a dictionary of return values, but in a switch-like implementation you want to store the functions themselves and not the return values.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to `await` only the function that you want to call. This way only the function corresponding to the argument is actually executed, while in your code all the calls are executed. You need to modify your code the following way.

```
async def reminder(self, ctx, *args): #args is the input from the user
     reminder_operations = {
            'add': self.reminder_add,
            'modify': self.reminder_modify,
            'delete': self.reminder_delete,
            'deleteall': self.reminder_delete_all
        }
     await reminder_operations[args[0]](ctx)
```